# My Model disappears into the Blender Universe

Tags: 3d-view

I was naming bones while rigging my model. While typing a bone name I saw my model move upwards without my knowing command. I eventually found it from a speck in the far distance. I scrolled it in successfully. But now it fails to respond to "View" commands. If I hit "7" for aerial view it disappears....again I find it as a speck and scroll it in. This happens with all "view" commands...

When I do locate it and try to drag it around it is as if there is a pivot point miles away and the slightest grab and drag sends it into oblivion.

My pivot point is set on default and my manipulator is set to Global. My model stays in the correct position on the grid all the time.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

try to select your model and press the period key on your numpad

Comment: I'm on a laptop but the period key did seem to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you mark it as the best answer if it was helpful